# How do I use BufReader's fill_buff and consume with TcpStream

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, compilation, lifetime, borrow-checker

The following code does not compile

```rust
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::net::{TcpListener};

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(format!("0.0.0.0:{}", 7007)).unwrap();
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
        let mut buf_reader = BufReader::new(&mut stream);
        let buf = buf_reader.fill_buf().unwrap();
        buf_reader.consume(buf.len())
    }
}
```

with error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `buf_reader` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
9  |         let buf = buf_reader.fill_buf().unwrap();
   |                   --------------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
10 |         buf_reader.consume(buf.len())
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------^
   |         |                  |
   |         |                  first borrow later used here
   |         second mutable borrow occurs here
```

I don't understand how this is different from the code used in the [documentation's example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#tymethod.fill_buf)

Comment: split the statement in two parts so that only one reference is used at a time.
`let amount = buf.len();` then `buf_reader.consume(amount);`

Answer (score 1):

The `fill_buf` method takes a [mutable reference to the struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) so that's one mutable borrow. The `consume` method *also* takes a `&mut self`, same as `fill_buf` does, so it's a no go if the compiler thinks you're still holding on to that first one.

In Rust mutable references are totally exclusive: you cannot be holding multiple mutable references to the same chunk of memory.

The difference between your code and the example from the docs is that the compiler knows in the doc example that you're done with `buf` (the first mutable borrow of the reader) as soon as you take the length so it can release the "lock" so to speak and be ready for when you call `.consume`.

Even though *logically* the two should be equivalent remember that the Rust compiler is doing all of this (very complicated) static analysis to both manage memory resources for you and guarantee some degree of thread safety without having to use an *actual* lock, and because of that it is to some degree limited by the *text* of the source, not its logical runtime semantics.

Just do what prog-fh suggests in the comments and split out the call to `.len`:

```
let length = buf.len(); // compiler can now drop first mutable borrow because we don't use buf again
buf_reader.consume(length); // second &mut is now exclusive
```